# Using WebGLOverlayView on a custom google.maps.MapType not working

Tags: webgloverlayview

I am using the google.maps.WebGLOverlayView to draw points and lines onto a google.maps.Map. This works fine for the existing MapTypes, e.g. roadmap or sattelite. However, when I create a custom MapType and add it to Map.mapTypesById and the mapTypeController, it does not show my WebGLOverlayView anymore. Switching between MapTypes works fine, and the other existing maps still show the overlay, but switching to my MapType does not.

My code for creating the map and the custom MapType is below:
(note that I am using some example code for the ImageMapType of https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes)

```
this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv as HTMLElement, {
    center,
    restriction: {
        latLngBounds: bounds,
        strictBounds: false,
    },
    zoom: zoomLevel,
    minZoom: minZoomLevel,
    maxZoom: maxZoomLevel,
    mapId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    streetViewControl: false,
    disableDefaultUI: false,
    gestureHandling: "auto",
    keyboardShortcuts: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ["roadmap", "satellite", "none"],
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
    },
    mapTypeId: "satellite",
});

const blankMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl(coord, zoom): string {
        let y = coord.y;
        let x = coord.x;

        // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
        // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
        const tileRange = Math.pow(2, zoom);

        // repeat across x-axis
        if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
            x = ((x % tileRange) + tileRange) % tileRange;
        }
        // repeat across y-axis
        if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
            y = ((y % tileRange) + tileRange) % tileRange;
        }

        const normalizedCoord = { x, y };

        if (!normalizedCoord) {
            return "";
        }

        const bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
        // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
        return `https://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw/${zoom}/${normalizedCoord.x}/${
            bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1
        }.jpg`;
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    opacity: 0.0,
    alt: "None",
    maxZoom: maxZoomLevel,
    minZoom: minZoomLevel,
    name: "None",
});
// this.map.overlayMapTypes.push(blankMapType);
this.map.mapTypes.set("none", blankMapType);
this.map.setMapTypeId("none");
```

What I am trying to achieve is having a blank/grey background, while still being able to draw using my overlayview. I tried to achieve this with creating a custom MapType, but if anyone has a different approach that also works, that would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WebGLOverlayView requires [vector map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/vector-map), when you set a new [base map type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#BaseMapTypes), the map will switch to raster map, and WebGLOverlayView won't work as there is no 3D context.

However, if you use [overlay map type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#OverlayMapTypes), and you should still be able to load a vector map (by providing your Map ID), and WebGLOverlayView should still function.